# How to iterate through an array of objects in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

So looking around and testing things I can easily iterate through an array or a list.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{inputs}}">
    <paper-input label={{item}} id={{item}} style="width:5em"></paper-   input>
</template>
```

However I am having problems iterating through an array of obects.

```
<iron-data-table id="outputtable" items="{{output}}">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[output]]">
                <data-table-column name="[[item.key]]">
                    <template>[[item.value]]</template>
                </data-table-column>
        </template>
</iron-data-table>
```

This code might not be right otherwise but I cannot get past the error

> Polymer::Attributes: couldn`t decode Array as JSON

The first example of me iterating through an array of strings, i actually want to iterate through an array of objects but have not been able to do so.

```
[{"uri":"/emoji/1"},{"uri":"/emoji/2"}]
```

Simple example of my array of objects.

```
<iron-ajax id="ajaxPost" url={{url}} handle-as="json" content-type="application/json" method="POST" on-response=clearAndOutput > </iron-ajax>


this.output [Object { uri="/emoji/1"}, Object { uri="/emoji/2"}, Object { uri="/emoji/3"}, 35 more...] 

clearAndOutput: function(data) {
    this.returnvalue = data.detail.response;
}
```

Comment: `clearAndOutput` sets `this.returnValue`. What sets `this.output`?

Comment: returnvalue is in a module I made called my-get. This is in my main work which has the property output, an event is triggered when returnvalue is changed and output becomes that value.

Answer (score 0):

In a [`dom-repeat`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-repeat), each array element of the `items` array is accessible by `item` inside the repeater template (although you could choose a different iterator name). If the array, named `"output"`, contained a `"uri"` attribute, you would iterate the array in the template like this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[output]]">
  <div>[[item.uri]]</div>
</template>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      output: {
        type: Array,
        value: () => [{"uri":"/emoji/1"},{"uri":"/emoji/2"}]
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[output]]">
        <div>[[item.uri]]</div>
      </template>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ameLPM?editors=1010)

The error you're seeing indicates that `"output"` is not actually an array, so you'll have to debug that (or provide additional information about how it's set in order to help troubleshoot).

Comment: properties: {
   output:{
    type: Array,
    value: []
   }
  },

Comment: I made the changes you said, same problem. I have been around the houses changing things. The code I wrote in the original post is not the code I thought would work, its just my last attempt.

Comment: But how are you populating `output`? What is the actual value of `output` that you're attempting to iterate?

Comment: iron-ajax which is within another element I made which using an event updates the property output.

Comment: The problem is likely that the response from that ajax request is not a JSON array. Check the actual value of `output`.

Comment: I have just double checked and its fine.

Comment: Hmm. It would help to see the `<iron-ajax>` and the value of `output` in your question.

Comment: <iron-ajax
   id="ajaxPost"
   url={{url}}
   handle-as="json"
   content-type="application/json"
   method="POST"
   on-response=clearAndOutput
  >
  </iron-ajax>

Comment: this.output
 
 [Object { uri="/emoji/1"}, Object { uri="/emoji/2"}, Object { uri="/emoji/3"}, 35 more...]

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code for `clearAndOutput()` and a log of the actual value of `output`?

Comment: Done, added all together.